# Tricky partial products in linear time

Tags: algorithm

Given is array containing N numbers, `A[0], A[1], ... A[N-1]`. Compute the array B of length N, such that

```
B[i] = A[0]*A[1]*...A[i-1]*A[i+1]...*A[N-1].
```

Algorithm should work in time `O(N),` memory `O(1)` and can't use division.

I tried by calculating the first few terms of then somehow combining them to get subsequent  product in constant time. But I was not able to combine them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The output is O(n) so when you say memory is O(1) do you mean the output 'B' has to replace A, or do you mean that we cannot use any memory other than A and B?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Yes. The extra space you can use is O(1)

Comment: So which is it, is the output array B separate from A or is it supposed to replace A?

Comment: How do you answer 'Yes' for a question asking you one of two possibilities? :P

Comment: @CaptainCodeman You asked "do you mean that we cannot use any memory other than A and B". I answered yes for that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go through the array twice. First go left-to-right, computing the partial products as you go and storing them into `B`. In a C-like pseudocode:

```
prod = 1;
for (n=0; n<N, n++) {
    B[n] = prod;
    prod *= A[n];
}
```

Next, reverse that, going right-to-left through the array, computing the partial products and multiplying them with the values already in `B`:

```
prod = 1;
for (n=N-1; n>=0; n--) {
    B[n] *= prod;
    prod *= A[n];
}
```

Comment: Correct. Nice Answer.

Comment: This is using O(n) extra memory, in the case that B is considered separate memory.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman As I read the question, that is what is asked for. I'm not sure it can even be done by modifying A in place.